# ctypes bindings for Subversion in windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, ctypes

Is there a binary installer or a faq for the new ctypes bindings for Subversion 1.6 in Windows (32 and 64bit)?

What library would you use to make an easy to deploy (both win32 and x64) svn client in python for svn version >= 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

You have the [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html) module which will allow you to do that:

Binary installer based on subversion 1.5.5